# Access a node.js server from a separate network

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, socket.io, webserver

I'm trying to create a simple live chat using node.js, socket.io and express. I've gotten this to run over my local network, but is there a way for someone else to connect through an entirely different internet connection without me paying for server space or getting a static IP?
Thanks for any help

Comment: This should not be a JS-Question but rather a Networking question. What Hardware are you working with? Can you build a [DMZ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DMZ_(computing)) in your Network?

You will need to somehow expose your server to the Network, and right now, there hopefully is a firewall in place somewhere that prohibits that.

Comment: Check out [WebRTC](https://webrtc.org/) which is for server-less peer to peer communications

Comment: I agree with @Klequex that this is a networking question.  But guiding you on the right path isn't much effort.  You need to find out which port your node app is running on, and expose that port on your router for your ip address.  If you are at 192.168.0.3 and the app is running on port 4000.  Other machines on your network could connect via 192.168.0.3:4000 if you open the port on your router.

Comment: @Nick Acosta, I've set my server to listen on port 8888. It's also accessible  to all machines connected to my network but what I'm asking is if there is some way for people to access it from an entirely different network

Comment: @Fool then go by what I said. Find a way to expose your Computer/Server to the Internet. If you have a standard issue router, search for port-forwarding and find a setup that suits you there. Exposing your Computer to the internet is dangerous at the least, but you can go with that, if you trust your visitors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at [DynDNS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_DNS), either on your side, or on your ISPs side.

What you want is a Record pointing dynamically to your IP. Then, in your Routers menu you need to find an option to enable `port-forwarding` from port `80` (or `443` if you use SSL) to your Computer and the Port of your Node App.

Then you can point a `CNAME` Record from any Domain you own to the DynDNS-Domain and share it with your contacts.